# TTK themes menu not properly displaying

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day!
My tkinter program will not properly display a menu.

Say the menu has 3 options, the first one will always disappear. Added some screenshots.[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yveNE.png) / [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHnbA.png)

Here's the code, if anyone knows a fix, please help!

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def show4():
    x=0

optionsmenu = [
    "Dark",
    "Mint",
    "Classic",
]
style = ThemedStyle(root)
style.set_theme("arc")
NightmodeO = StringVar()
drop = ttk.OptionMenu(root, NightmodeO, *optionsmenu)
b1=ttk.Button(root, text='Set theme', command=show4).grid(row=0)
drop.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a default option, like `optionsmenu[0]`:

`drop = ttk.OptionMenu(root, NightmodeO, optionsmenu[0], *optionsmenu)`

Comment: Thank you my friend. Is it possible to put commands in menus like the one I have right now?

Comment: You can call your function with `command=show4` like so: `drop = ttk.OptionMenu(root, NightmodeO, optionsmenu[0], *optionsmenu, command=show4)`. If you want to change the theme instantly (and get rid of the button) you should change your `def show4():` to `def show4(*args):` and inside the function: `style.set_theme(NightmodeO.get())`. That will work as long as you have those themes configured. For the default themes see [link](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes/tree/master/ttkthemes/themes)

Comment: Yess! I have done that already in my main program, thank you for thinking with me my man. I don't really want full themes for my program, I cannot really interract with the button sizes, colors and such. Or are there some arguments I'm not aware of?

Comment: Colors i don't think so, but you can change button size in a multitude of ways. You're not supposed to do that because themed buttons are there to get a uniform size but if you really want to, you can.  Width can be done easily by setting `width=`. Height is a little more work; you could use padding or grid it and set a minimum size for the row or you can even put a transparent image of your desired size on it.